# Inquiry on possibility of providing ALSpeechRecognition access to Google speech-to-text API or other online API with huge vocabulary list

Tags: pepper, google-speech-to-text-api

**Problem description**
I want to provide a pepper robot the ability to recognize speech and convert it to text using a huge vocabulary list. Is there a way to provide the `setVocabulary` method with some external vocabulary list from some other API such as the `google-speech-to-text` API so I don't have to manually set what words and phrases to recognize? Basically much like how the `recognize_google` method in the python library `speech_recognition` operates.
Or Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way? Any alternatives are welcome.

**My current set up**
I am currently using the `ALSpeechRecognition` API (Aldebaran software), with it's `setVocabulary` method to set a list of phrases to recognize. I subscribe to the `WordRecognized` event which stores any recognized words or phrase. I retrieve recognized words and phrases using the `getData` method from the `ALMemory` API.

**This is the python script I currently use to access text from speech:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
from naoqi import ALProxy
import time
ROBOT_IP = "130.191.48.26"

# Creates a proxy on the speech-recognition module
asr = ALProxy("ALSpeechRecognition", ROBOT_IP, 9559)
mem = ALProxy("ALMemory", ROBOT_IP, 9559)
asr.setLanguage("English")

# Example: Adds "yes", "no" and "please" to the vocabulary (without wordspotting)
vocabulary = ["yes", "no", "please listen to me","okay"]
asr.setVocabulary(vocabulary, False)

# Start the speech recognition engine with user Test_ASR
asr.subscribe("WordRecognized")
print('Speech recognition engine started')
time.sleep(5)
word = mem.getData("WordRecognized")
print(word)
asr.unsubscribe("WordRecognized")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ALSpeechRecognition](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/audio/alspeechrecognition.html) interface is useful just for a few short words or phrases to choose from. For long phrase lists, it is better to use the [ALDialog](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/dialog/aldialog.html) Pepper interface. Or you can call the Google Speech API externally (see e.g. the function [`recognize_Google()` in the Pepper-Controller](https://github.com/incognite-lab/Pepper-Controller/blob/99b9fc93bfa20473f5b5f65f5c01a8036a6f8917/pepper/robot.py#L1099)), but this adds an unwanted delay to the robot speech processing.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please, how may I go about achieving this second option with the recognize_Google() method as I ideally want the pepper to autonomously access a large vocabulary list without an manual setting.

Comment: Edit: I am so sorry, for some reason it did not occur to me you already provided me links to research on.